# Running Utilization Job multiple times a day

Tags: scheduled-apex, financialforce

I am trying to schedule a job to run several times a day.

It's a Utilization job which is part of the FinancialForce PSA application. The UtilizationScheduler class has this signature:

```
global class UtilizationScheduler implements System.Schedulable {
    global UtilizationScheduler(pse__Utilization_Calculation__c calc) {

    }
    global UtilizationScheduler(pse__Utilization_Calculation__c calc, String cronDayParm) {

    }
    global void execute(System.SchedulableContext sc) {

    }
}
```

I think I am close with:

```
System.schedule('Utilisation 1am 1pm 5pm', '0 0 1,13,17 * * ?', new UtilizationScheduler());
```

But I get an error: `Invalid type: UtilizationScheduler` by Executing Anonymous Apex from the Developer Console.

How should I call the UtilizationScheduler Class? How do I tell it what Utilization Calculation (a custom object in FinF PSA) to use?

Apologies - this is my first foray into Apex code. Help greatfully received!

Answer (score 2):

Classes installed from a package have a namespace. To call it, you should use the appropriate namespace:

```
System.schedule(
  'Utilisation 1am 1pm 5pm', 
  '0 0 1,13,17 * * ?', 
  new namespace.UtilizationScheduler()
);
```

I'm not familiar with what the namespace for this package is, but you can find it in Setup > Package Manager. Just replace `namespace.` with the appropriate namespace for the class.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you @sfdcfox! The namespace is `pse` (if you care!)
I'm now getting the error `Constructor not defined: [pse.UtilizationScheduler].<Constructor>`. I need to give it the `pse__Utilization_Calculation__c calc` somehow. Any thoughts?

Comment: @StevieP you can try to query one from the database, `[select id from pse__Utilization_Calculation__c];` or you can create one manually, `pse__Utilization_Calculation__c calc = new pse__Utilization_Calculation__c();` Make sure populate any required fields.

Comment: Boom! `pse__Utilization_Calculation__c calc = [select id from pse__Utilization_Calculation__c where Name='MyUtilCalcName']`
I owe you a beer!